# Display all the posts except selected post by category wise

Tags: wordpress

I have displayed "Home" category posts home page. Clicked on "Readmore" First post.
It is displaying all the details of first post.

And now i want to display all the posts below "first post" with "Readmore".

Here is my code, and it is displaying some other category posts.

```
<?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  $catID = the_category_ID($echo=false); //Current selected category ID
  $catPost = get_posts('cat=$catID&posts_per_page=3');
  foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
  <h1><a><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
  <p class="postinfo">Written by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
  Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
  Categories: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
  <hr />
<?php  endforeach;?>
```

[image]

Posts Page

[image]

Comment: you mean to displaying all the posts by category wise or current category wise.

Comment: No. Want to display selected category posts only. Not all the categories

Comment: Yes yes. Current category posts

Comment: use like get_posts('category_name=CATEGORYNAME&posts_per_page=5');  or use wp_query like   $getpost = new WP_Query('category_name=my_second_category', 'posts_per_page'=>3); ?>

Comment: How can i use this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way ..

```
<?php
    global $post;
    if(is_category() || is_single()){
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category)
    {
    $current = $category->cat_ID;
    $current_name = $category->cat_name;

    //query_posts("cat=". $current);

    $myposts = get_posts(array('category__in' => array($current)));

    //$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=50&category='.$current); 

    //query_posts(array('category__in' => array(11)));
        }
    }

    foreach($myposts as $post) :
    setup_postdata($post); 

    ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, This is what i want, but want to display all the posts except selected post.

Comment: I have 4 posts. i selected Post-2, And want to display posts-1,3 and 4.

Comment: have you used ' numberposts' in post argument ?

Comment: This answer is very useful. How can i display all posts except selected one.